# REgex not working for white space javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate string which can take only alphanumeric values without space.

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u00E0-\u00FC ]+/gi, '')
```

I used above code but seems still it is taking white space. Did not able to find the right way to fix it.

Comment: try: str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u00E0-\u00FC]+/gi, '')

Comment: You put a space in your set of accepted chars so yes, it is taking white spaces.

Comment: Ohh, I see.. I should not put white space . I was thinking it will take only ascii code.

Comment: Space is a valid ASCII (and unicode) char.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space in regexp

```
  str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u00E0-\u00FC]+/gi, '')
  //  ---------------------------------^ here
```